# php: create custom-sized thumbnail

Tags: php, image, resize

i'm familiar with resizing and cropping images under php using imagecopyresampled but now i'm having a special problem:
the task is cropping a large image from eg. 1600x1200 to 500x120, which means resizing down to 500px and crop its height that it'S 120px. is there some easy way or do i need to calculate the cropping values all on my own? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is PHP library that could help you out called PHPThumb. You can find here https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb

They have an adaptive resize method that does what you're looking for. https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself.

I don't know if you want to crop or not, so here's how to calculate the values for both:

**Scale image**: resize to fit within new w x h keeping aspect ratio (so 1 side may be shorter than specified)

```
function calc_scale_dims($width_orig, $height_orig, $max_width, $max_height) { 

    $new_width=$width_orig;
    $new_height=$height_orig;
    $ratioh = $max_height/$new_height;
    $ratiow = $max_width/$new_width;
    $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow);
    // New dimensions
    $dims["w"] = intval($ratio*$new_width);
    $dims["h"] = intval($ratio*$new_height); 

    return $dims;
}
```

**Resize and Crop**: Resizes image and crops it to fit into the specified w x h if new aspect ratio is different (e.g. if aspect ratios are different, image will be resized to match specified size on the short size and the longer size if cropped in the middle)

```
function calc_crop_resize_dims($width_orig, $height_orig, $new_width, $new_height) { 

    //Calculate scaling
    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
    $ratio_new = $new_width/$new_height;

    if ($ratio_new < $ratio_orig) {
       $copy_width = $height_orig*$ratio_new;
       $copy_height = $height_orig;
    } else {
       $copy_width = $width_orig;
       $copy_height = $width_orig/$ratio_new;
    }

    //point to start copying from (to copy centre of image if we are cropping)
    $dims["src_x"] = ($width_orig - $copy_width)/2;
    $dims["src_y"] = ($height_orig - $copy_height)/2;
    $dims["copy_width"] = $copy_width;
    $dims["copy_height"] = $copy_height;

    return $dims;
}
```